# Canvas using react three fiber

Tags: reactjs

I try to load a fbx animation using react three fiber but it didn't work, the 3d model is shown with texture but no animation

There is some errors

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew3xW.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rejbh.png)

Comment: Please include all code as text, not images.

Comment: please do not use links for code and errors copy/past them directly in the question for a better lisibility